# Why doesn't multisampling work?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, multisampling

I'm trying to get multisampling to work in my OpenGL ES app.

Framebuffer setup code:

```
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &framebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &colorRenderbuffer);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, framebuffer);  
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);

GLint backingWidth;
GLint backingHeight;
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &sampleFramebuffer);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, sampleFramebuffer);

glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &sampleColorRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, sampleColorRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, 4, GL_RGBA8_OES, backingWidth, backingWidth);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, sampleColorRenderbuffer);

glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &sampleDepthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, sampleDepthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, 4, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingWidth);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, sampleDepthRenderbuffer);
```

Rendering code:

```
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, sampleFramebuffer);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

GLfloat vertices[] = {
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    2.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f
};
glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 3);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, sampleFramebuffer);
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, framebuffer);
glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE();

glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
```

Result:

[image: Rendering result]

As you can see triangle still has aliased sides.

Comment: I can't find a problem, other than perhaps your assumption that 4 is an acceptable level of multisampling when you should be querying `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_SAMPLES_APPLE, &maxSamplesAllowed)`. I've specifically checked your code line for line against some of mine and you seem to be doing everything flawlessly. If you perform a quick `glCheckFramebufferStatusOES` on the `sampleFramebuffer` do you get an appropriate response?

Comment: @Tommy 1) There is an error. I bind `sampeFramebuffer` as renderbuffer in the beginning of rendering code (thanks to Mārtiņš Možeiko). 2) iPhone supports exactly 4 samples. 3) `glCheckFramebufferStatusOES` reports framebuffer is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sampleFramebuffer is framebuffer, not renderbuffer. But you are binding it as renderbuffer in rendering code. That's wrong. You should check OpenGL errors by calling glGetError - that would tell you which GL call is invalid.

Your rendering code should start with following line:

```
glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, sampleFramebuffer);
```

Rest of it is ok. But to improve performance you could use glDiscardFramebufferEXT call on your multisampled framebuffer after Resolve call:

```
glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE();
const GLenum discards[]  = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT};
glDiscardFramebufferEXT(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE,2,discards);
```

Comment: You are right, there is an error in bind function call.
I have fixed it. I see performance drop, it means it now uses `sampleFramebuffer`. But it is still doesn't see any visual changes. I get error 1282 (0x0502, `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`) after I call `glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE()`.

Comment: To be correct, I don't see any visual difference on iPhone 3G. But simulator and iPhone 4S render something unpredictable.

Comment: According to documentation ( http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/APPLE/APPLE_framebuffer_multisample.txt ) glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE returns GL_INVALID_OPERATION, if 1) SAMPLE_BUFFERS for the read framebuffer is zero, 2) SAMPLE_BUFFERS for the draw framebuffer is greater than zero, 3) the read framebuffer or draw framebuffer does not have a color attachment, 4) dimensions of the read and draw framebuffers are not identical, 5) components in the format of the draw framebuffer's color attachment are not present in the format of the read framebuffer's color attachment.

Comment: Btw, I suggest choosing manual antialiasing (like FXAA shader), instead of hardware MSAA. I can turn out that it is faster - at least from my experiments with Android GLES programming.

Comment: I have decided to move INVALID_OPERATION question to separate topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497936/resolvemultisampleframebufferapple-generates-invalid-operation

Comment: There's another error: backingWidth is passed as height (last argument) in  `glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, 4, GL_RGBA8_OES, backingWidth, backingWidth);` (2x). As a result your code doesn't work in non-square views, also.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's multi-sampling doesn't completely get rid of the aliased edges, particularly at angles near 0, 90, 180, & 270.  But it should help to soften them.

In some of my tests I've found onlly a slight difference with it on and off.  And you have to decide if it's worth the cost in your app.  For example on the iPhone the pixels density is so small that it doesn't make a difference to my eye.  On tvOS however the aliasing is quite noticable on like a 45" screen.